# Arrangement : how many unique possibilities for x elements among n

Tags: php, math, probability

I'm not that good at math, so I'm stuck here.
I need to get the total number of possible arrangement (I think, or permutations maybe?) of X elements amongst N.

- I want to pick X distinct elements amongst N (`N>=X`)
- order DOES matter
- each element can not come more than once in a combination

=> For exemple, given `$N = count(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`, a valid combination of `$X=6` elements could be :

```
 - 1,4,5,3,2,8
 - 4,2,1,9,7,3
```

What formula do I need to use in PHP to get the total number of possibilities?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was downvoted ? Did I ask anything wrong / stupid ?

Answer (score 2):

There are N choices for the first element, N-1 for the second (as you have already chosen 1) then N-2 choices for the third and so on. You can express using factorials this a N! / (N-X-1)!. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutations

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I think it N! / (N-X)! though ? At least according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it.

```
$set = array(A,B,C,D,E,F,G);
$n = count($set);
$k = 6;

if($n>0)
{
    if($k < $n)
    { 
        $outcomes = gmp_fact($n) / gmp_fact($n-$k);
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $outcomes = gmp_fact($n);
    }
} else { $outcomes = 0; }
```

where gmp_fact($n) is the php function for $n! (n factorial), which means N x (N-1) x ... x 1